# How to ignore all characters except first character?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char letter;
    while (cin>>letter)
    {
        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a':
                cout<<"ant"<<endl;
                break;
            default :
                cout <<"enter only lower cases letters "<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any feature of c++ that ignores the characters next to first character? Because i.e., if I enter `aaa` it displays `ant ant ant`, so I want to get rid of this part. I hope you get my question.

Comment: you could remove the while loop?

Comment: _I hope you get my question_ I don't think so

Comment: @UKMonkey No, you don't understand me then, I am supposed to write a program when I input any letter it displays a word starts with that letter so I want to get rid of all characters next to first character. so When I enter aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa however how many 'a' it only displays ant.

Comment: So you want to be able to continuously type any letter, so long as you don't enter the same letter twice in a row?

Comment: @TreytenCarey Exactly.

Comment: Why would you write a program to do that? It makes no sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But then neither does Facebook.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have an assignment to do that. this is a part of a program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read a string and then switch on the first character. Like this.

```
int main () {
    string word;
    while (cin >> word) {
        switch (word[0]) {
        case 'a':
            cout << "ant" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "enter only lower cases letters " << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is actually what I am looking forward, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the user input as a `std::string` and then just look at the first character from it for your switch statement. This will ignore anything the user inputs after the first character. I can't imagine the use case for this, but I believe this is what you're asking for.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word)
    {
        char letter = word[0];
        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a':
                std::cout << "ant" << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "please enter only lower case letters" << std::endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but can you tell me what is the benefit of int argc, char *argv[]?

Comment: These are not necessary for your program, but `argv` and `argc` are how command line arguments are passed to `main()` in C++ (and C). The `argc` variable will be the number of strings pointed to by `argv`.  If you were to ever have command line options to your program, that is what you use.

Answer (score 0):

Read chars repeatedly and keep track of what's been added

```
#include <set>

int main () {
    char letter;
    std::set<char> used;
    while (cin >> letter) {
        if (!used.insert(letter)[1])   // note returns a pair; 2nd item ([1]) is true if it didn't exist before
            continue;
        switch (letter) {
        case 'a':
            cout << "ant" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "enter only lower cases letters " << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only first char will be saved

```
int main()
{
    char c = 0;
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should I include some libraries, because it says getchar() is not declared in the scope?